# How do I fetch this substring using awk?

Tags: unix, awk

I have a string let's say

```
k=CHECK_${SOMETHING}_CUSTOM_executable.acs
```

Now I want to fetch only **CUSTOM_executable** from the above string. This is what I have tried so far in Unix

```
echo $k|awk -F '_' '{print $2}'
```

Can you explain how can i do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the variable `${SOMETHING}` has the value `SOMETHING` just for simplicity.

The following assignment, therefore,

```
k=CHECK_${SOMETHING}_CUSTOM_executable.acs
```

sets the value of `k` to `CHECK_SOMETHING_CUSTOM_executable.acs`.

When split into fields on `_` by `awk -F '_'` (note the single quotes aren't necessary here).

You get the following fields:

```
$ echo "$k" | awk -F _ '{for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) {print i"="$i}}'
0=CHECK_SOMETHING_CUSTOM_executable.acs
1=CHECK
2=SOMETHING
3=CUSTOM
4=executable.acs
```

So to get the output you want simply use

```
echo "$k" | awk -F _ -v OFS=_ '{print $3,$4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$ echo "$k"
CHECK_111_CUSTOM_executable.acs
```

code:

```
echo "$k" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"}{sub(/.acs/, "");print $3, $4}'
```

Comment: Hi Suppose my SOMETHING is 111_111 ? Then how can i handle this?

Comment: Then you have to use $4, $5

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), it can be done in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) easily. I assume that `$SOMETHING` does not contains `_` characters (also `CUSTOM` and `executable` part is just some text, they also not contains `_`). Then:

```
k=CHECK_${SOMETHING}_CUSTOM_executable.acs
l=${k#*_}; l=${l#*_}; l=${l%.*};
```

This cuts anything from the beginning to the 2nd `_` char, and chomps off anything after the last `.` char. Result is put into the `l` env.var.

If `$SOMETHING` may contain `_` then a little bit work has to be done (I assume the `CUSTOM` and `executable` part does not contain `_`):

```
k=CHECK_${SOMETHING}_CUSTOM_executable.acs
l=${k%_*}; l=${l%_*}; l=${k#${l}_*}; l=${l%.*};
```

This chomps off everything after the last but one `_` character, the cuts the result off from the original string. The last statement chomps the extension off. The result is in `l` env.var.

Or it can be done using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

```
[[ $k =~ ([^_]+_[^_]+)\.[^.]+$ ]] && l=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

This matches any string containing two words separated by `_` and finished with `.<extension>`. The extension part is chomped off and result is in `l` env.var.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if `SOMETHING` variable is having `111_222_333` (or) `111_222_333_444`,

Use this:

```
$ k=CHECK_${SOMETHING}_CUSTOM_executable.acs

$ echo $k | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"}{ print $(NF-1),$NF }'
```

(Or)

```
 echo $k | awk -F_ '{ print $(NF-1), $NF }' OFS=_
```

**Explanation :**

`NF` - The number of fields in the current input record.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```sh
awk -F[._] '{print $3"_"$4}' <<<"$k"

CUSTOM_executable
```

The `-F[._]` defines both dot and underline as field separator. Then awk prints the filed number 3 and 4 from `$k` as input.

If the k contains `k='CHECK_${111_111}_CUSTOM_executable.acs'`, then use filed with numbers $4 and $5:

```
awk -F[._] '{print $4"_"$5}' <<<"$k"
```

```
CHECK_${111_111}_CUSTOM_executable.acs
| $1| |$2 | |$3| | $4 | |   $5   | |$6|
```